# Recursive algorithm to return nested structure of a recursive QuadTree

Tags: python, recursion, quadtree

I've been using this recurivse Quadtree from http://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter2/fig_quadtree_example.html

on some data. But I now need a nested representation of the structure of the result.

The structure is something like:

```
QT.children[0].children[0].children[0].children
```

Here children is the recursive element which is a list including further `QuadTree()` instances. The lowest depth has no children (`len(children)` is 0) and is the representation i want to access. In this case therefore to access the data I would do

```
>>> print QT.children[0].children[0].children[0].data

'hello this is from 0,0,0'
```

Ultimately i want a representation of the data at the lowest level like:

```
[ [
    [  
      ['Hello this is from 0,0,0'],
      ['hello this is from 0,0,1'] 
    ],
    [
      ['hello this is from 0,1,0' ]
    ]
   ]
   ['hello this is from 1' ]
]
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

To modify the representation of an object, you must overwrite the  __ repr __ function, which returns the string form of your object. In your case, you could want to have a recursive function that returns a list (or an array) of your nested data and use that as the representation.